# Ошибка в боте @clear.error

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Я делаю своего бота на пайтон и хотел сделать право на комманды и ошибка в @clear.error

хотя у других людей ее нету что делать?
Пример Код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def Hello(ctx):
     await ctx.send("Привет!")




@clear.error
async def clear_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("У вас нету прав!")



bot.run("")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас в коде нигде не прописано, что такое clear. Оно должно или описано в самом вашем файле как класс или функция, или откуда-то импортироваться.

Answer (score 0):

У вас нет команды clear. Дам вам готовую кмд

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions( manage_messages = True )
async def clear( ctx, amount = 1 ):
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = 1 )
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = amount )
```